# Postgres: Storing a task instruction to be run on a schedule, with multiple workers

Tags: scala, postgres, scheduling

As a prerequisite I will say that we are wedded to postgres to provide this solution.

This is a very broad problem, and I think it must be solved many times over, but unfortunately as it's so general I can't find any really interesting solutions online.

We have a task we need to run, say "reindex customers". This needs to happen every `n` seconds. The task definition needs to be set in the DB. There will be many tasks set, usually only strings such as `"reindex"` that will be interpreted by code to be a certain function.

We have multiple workers who will all read this scheduling data. For redundancy purposes. Each period, `n` seconds, precisely one worker must process the task related to the database row.

What is the best way to store/retrieve/annotate this information in a postgres DB?

I don't have any solution in mind that covers all requirements at the moment.

For context, the worker code will be run in standalone scala processes. There is no further infrastructure available for use.

Comment: Well, the worker code doesn't *have* to live in Scala.  It could be as simple as a Stored Procedure in Postgres.  For information on how to run periodic jobs in Postgresql, see [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/).

Comment: I think my use of the word reindexing was a poor choice. These tasks will be arbitrary business tasks, involving many external services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases can be used as a job queue, though it's not necessarily ideal. Because Postgres supports ACID modifications, it is easy to ensure that exactly one process will receive a job. Here, the workers could poll for due jobs with a query that simultaneously updates the next execution time. This statement will only succeed for one worker per task at a time.

Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks(id, next_execution, every_n_seconds);
...

UPDATE tasks
SET next_execution = next_execution + every_n_seconds
WHERE next_execution >= current_time
RETURNING id;
```

Of course, it is more difficult to ensure that tasks are distributed *fairly* between workers.

If the reindexing to be performed is internal to the Postgres database, it could be more appropriate to write a stored procedure.

Comment: That seems pretty perfect to me - thank you. It will work for my situation, I do not need fair distibution, only precisely once distribution. The idea of updating the execution time at the same time as a successful poll did not occur to me